# Is there a way to do route comparison between 2 routes using any Map API

Tags: google-maps, routes

If James is going from Point A to Point B, 
and Charlie is going from Point C to Point D,

And Point C and D lies on the route of Point A and B (using Google Map where the route is highlighted in blue)

Can it be done such that the program will match these two separate routes together

Answer (score 0):

The directions API [gives you](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses) a `start_location` and an `end_location` latitude and longitude for each step in the route - a simple solution would be:

```
hasStart = false
for all points P in route1:
      if (hasStart == false && P.start == route2.start) hasStart = true; 
      if (hasStart == true && P.end == route2.end) // the routes match
```

Of course if you want to know if route1 is inside route2, you'd have to do this twice. Also, you might want to tolerate a bit of error in the `P.start == route2.start`, so that you'd also pick up routes that go very close to each other (eg the next street corner, or whatever).

There are probably better ways, but I'd say this is simple and readable, and likely to be fast enough :)